# Visual Studio 2019: Failed to initialize the powershell host

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I know my question is very similar to this one ([Visual Studio Package Installation Error: "Failed to initialize the PowerShell host."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269514/visual-studio-package-installation-error-failed-to-initialize-the-powershell-h)). But still the answer that was given there didn't solve my issue.

So like the guy in the link above I have a problem in Visual Studio when I try to create a Web Forms Application or when I want to download and install some Nuget packages (example: AWS DynamoDB sdk) it gives me this error:

> failed to initialize the PowerShell host. If your PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager Console to initialize the host first.

When I did some browsing I came across this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

But that didn't help. I still got the error. In the link above someone shares this command:

```
start-job { Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted } -RunAs32 | wait-job | Receive-Job
```

But I don't really know what difference it makes or what it actually does. After trying the first command and doing:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

I got a response that the value is Unrestricted. But in the other command it was still AllSigned. I also tried running Visual Studio as administrator and that didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried to repair VS installation? Start Visual Studio Installer with admin rights and try to do repair for VS and powershell if it is visible.

Comment: I tried that, but the Visual studio installer wanted to update, which for some reason fails every time, so is it a good idea if I reinstall Visual Studio?

Comment: Use Tools/Nuget Packet Manager/Packet Manager Console. Type the `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in this VS window. The Packet Manager Console is a dedicated host, and using regular PowerShell may not set the setting for the Packet Manager.

Comment: @Hazrelle The problem when I want to try this is, I can't type in that window of Package manager console.

Comment: I would reinstall VS if you can't update the VS Installer. Is this your personal machine or corporate machine? What version of VS 2019 you are trying to use ?

Comment: @Jakub This is my personal computer. I have community edition if that is what you mean by version.

Comment: Also when i press NuGet package manager console it gives me an error: The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, that there was a certificate from Microsoft on the Untrusted list, and I needed to delete it, and now it works.